# Create Web App with Specific Location

Tags: msdeploy

I am trying to create an IIS Web Application with a customized location and after reading the documentation I think i can't do it with only using the createApp.

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:createApp -dest:createApp="Default Web Site/MyApp",filePath="C:\MyCustomDir"
```

**Error: The provider 'createApp' does not support the 'filePath' setting. Supported settings are (managedRuntimeVersion, enable32Bi
tAppOnWin64, managedPipelineMode, authType, computerName, encryptPassword, includeAcls, password, prefetchPayload, userName, wmsvc
).
Error count: 1.**

Answer (score 4):

First off, as the error message shows, filePath isn't a *setting* for createApp -- it's actually a *provider* of its own that can copy individual files (see [Web Deploy filePath Provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207414%28WS.10%29.aspx)).

[createApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee522996%28WS.10%29.aspx) only creates the definition for a web application in IIS configuration (the apphost.config file) - it doesn't actually create a folder for the web application. So, you're better off using the [iisApp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569054%28WS.10%29.aspx) provider, which creates the app definition in IIS *and* the folder for you.

Following the intent of your example, I tried the following command using iisApp:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:iisApp="c:\MyCustomDir" -dest:iisapp="Default Web Site/MyApp"
```

The command works, but the problem is that since you are creating an app under the Default Web Site (and with the iisApp and createApp commands you must have an existing IIS site under which the app will be created), the folder specified in the source was ignored. Instead, iisApp automatically created a MyApp folder under the folder for the Default Web site, which in this case was `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp`.

If you want to change the folder for the app to some other location, it looks like you have to do it after the fact. In IIS Manager, you can do it by selecting **MyApp** in the Connections pane, clicking **Basic Settings** in the Action pane, and then changing the **Physical path** setting in the Edit Application dialog box.